# Format numbers as billions / millions / thousands, smartly

Tags: excel, numbers, format, google-sheets, excel-formula

Any recipes out there for a "smart" number formatting formula that's "scale-aware," a la Rails ActionView's [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) method?

I would expect to enter a number like: 1,816,724 and see **1.8M** (or enter 2,394 and see **2.4K**).

Comment: you want only K and M?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To format conditionally using Billions / Millions / Thousands in Google Spreadsheets or Excel, you can use:

```
[<999950]0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"
```

[image]

To apply this setting in Google sheets, goto `Format > Number > Custom Number Format` and copy paste the above format string.

To learn more about formatting options, go to https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470#zippy=%2Ccustom-number-formatting

Comment: `[<999950]0.0, "K" [$€-1];[<999950000]0.0,, "M" [$€-1];0.0,,, "B" [$€-1] ;@` improved a bit

Comment: This is incredible.  Can you explain all the syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Select the cells to receive a custom number format and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. When the **Format Cells** dialog opens, go to the *Number* tab and choose *Custom* from the list down the left side. Supply the following for the *Type:*,

```
[>999999]0.0,,\M;[>999]0.0,K;0
```

Note that *M* is a reserved character in a format mask and must be escaped with a backslash to become literal. You can also wrap it in quotes but since I use custom number formats in VBA's [.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224873(v=office.11).aspx), I prefer the escape character to avoid having to deal with quotes within quoted strings. Your results should resemble the following:

[image: M and K custom number format]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this one:

```
=IF(A1<1000,A1,IF(A1<1000000,ROUND(A1/1000,1)&"K",ROUND(A1/1000000,1)&"M"))
```

supposing that your number is in **A1**.